# It is possible to give different Google API Key in ASP.NET Google maps Application?

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, subgurim-maps

```
  I am using googlemaps.subgurim.net in my application,it is possible to set different GOOGLE API KEY to different users based on their logins.
              web.config:        
            <add key="googlemaps.subgurim.net" value="xxxxxxxxx"/>       
            .aspx:        
            <cc1:GMap ID="GMap1" runat="server" Height="805px" Width="800px" />       
            .aspx.cs:        
            string sMapKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googlemaps.subgurim.net"];
            GeoCode objAddress = new GeoCode();          
            objAddress=Map.geoCodeRequest(newGLatLng(Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][0]),Convert.ToDouble(status.Rows[0][1])), sMapKey);
                                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                    if (objAddress.valid)
                                    {
                                        sb.Append(objAddress.Placemark.address.ToString());
                                        lbladd.Text = sb.ToString();
                                    }
```

I am using googlemaps.subgurim.net in my application,it is possible to set different GOOGLE API KEY to different users based on their logins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. You will need to persist their API Key in their user record e.g. in the Database then in your Api script just switch in the variable

Web Forms

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=User.ApiKey%>&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

MVC

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=@Model.UserApiKey&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

Might be worth in your Getter that if their APi key is null, then switch in your default.

Comment: here i am using : <add key="googlemaps.subgurim.net" value="xxxx"/> i am not using javascript Google controls...

Comment: Are you trying to do
string sMapKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googlemaps.subgurim.net"]; OR string sMapKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["googlemaps.xyz.net"];

Comment: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[User.ApiKey]; where user is your user class??